# Linking 2 tables in a single PHP output.. best way? PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, join

I'm trying to link two tables. I want a user on my site to be able to 'follow' a user and see their updates. I have two tables

```
Users | Publish
===============
userid|userid
follow|publish_id
      |publish_content
```

In users I have their userID and who they are following. In the publish table I have what they posted, their logged ID's and the content. If I want to display this to the follower, what is the best way of going about it? Linking up the two tables with the posts that the user would want to see? Would joining be the best route? Thanks!

Comment: How is the list of users following the user stored???

Comment: They are being stored in a TEXT field. I.E. I am user1 you are user2. If I am following you and member three the text field will read "2,3."

Comment: Then think the answer I have posted will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.userid a.publish_id, a.publish_content FROM Publish a, Users b WHERE a.userid IN b.follow
```

if `follow` is of type `varchar` and gives the list of friends the user if following in a comma separated format, this query will give the details of all the users the present user if following

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT publish_id, publish_content 
     FROM Publish JOIN Users ON Publish.userid = Users.userid 
     WHERE Users.follow = "%user%"
```